# The "modified timestamp" changed via a cut and paste

Tags: files, filesystem, ext4, fat32

I needed to copy a file from one Ubuntu system to another Ubuntu system.

I checked the "modified timestamp" of the original file and it was April 21 15:27:31. I copied and pasted to a removable Flash drive.

Suppose the removable Flash drive has the attributes: GPT EXT4. The timestamp of the file is 15:27:31 on the removable drive. This removable Flash drive was formatted on Ubuntu with `gparted`. I cut and pasted to the destination system and the timestamp is still 15:27:31 on the destination system.

Suppose the removable Flash drive has the attributes: MSDOS MBR FAT32. This was probably formatted on Windows 10 and these attributes are from my handwritten label of what is likely diplayed by `gparted` on Ubuntu. The file on the removable drive has the timestamp 15:27:31. The file is cut and pasted from the removable drive to the destination system. The timestamp is now 15:27:30 on the destination system.

Clearly the solution is to use the GPT EXT4 device even though it is less portable than the MSDOS MBR FAT32 device in a "mixed" environment of Windows and Ubuntu machines.

Why did the timestamp change in the case of the MSDOS MBR FAT32 removable drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) has a resolution of *"2 seconds for last modified time"*, while *"[ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) provides timestamps measured in nanoseconds"*. So it seems safe to say FAT is losing the extra second of precision, though I'm not sure why it only "takes effect" when moving the file to another filesystem. It might be a rounding error. This post by Raymond Chen might have some clues: [Why does the timestamp of a file increase by up to 2 seconds when I copy it to a USB thumb drive?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140903-00/?p=83)

BTW, another reason not to trust timestamps on FAT: [they don't support time zones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/SysInfo/file-times).